# full text search for phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

So I wonder if there is any library I could use for full-text search with phoenix framework? I tried to google something, even in erlang, but found only some really old libraries ...

Comment: You should rather check how your database supports this functionality. For example: http://blog.rokkincat.com/postgres-full-text-search-in-ecto/

Comment: @JoséValim oh I see, I'll try it, thank you. And I wanted to thank you for all the work you've done to come up with this framework, it's amazing.

Comment: Link from @JoséValim is no longer available, but Wayback has it at http://web.archive.org/web/20181006145249/https://rkkn.netlify.com/blog/engineering/postgres-full-text-search-in-ecto/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're asking about something native to the BEAM.  Otherwise, I'm not sure why you couldn't use [Solr/Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).  Granted you'd have to write some glue code but I don't think there's any solution where a bit of glue code wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend looking at ElasticSearch as well. I used it in a previous project and it is quite powerful.